Show that Z has a Standard Normal Distribution – Support Issue?
I'm working through a practice in Casella & Berger:
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are identically and independently distributed as $N(0,1)$. Define a new random variable $Z$ as follows:
$Z = X$ if $XY > 0$
$Z = -X$ if $XY < 0$
I am required to show that $Z$ also has a standard normal distribution.
I can show that $Z$ seems to have the same cumulative distribution function (CDF) as $N(0,1)$ by looking at the definition of the CDF. However, I'm confused about the support of $Z$. Since $Z$ is not defined for $XY = 0$, it seems that the support of $Z$ does not include $0$. This makes me doubt that $Z$ is actually a standard normal distribution, as its support appears different from $\mathbb{R}$.
Could someone please point out where I am going wrong in my reasoning?

The distribution function of $Z$ does not depend on the value of $Z$ on a set of probability 0. It doesn't matter if $Z$ is undefined on this set.

@Ricky Thank you for your clarification! I appreciate it. Does your comment involve more rigorous probability concept? Cause it still feel strange to me that if you look at the support of Z, it is R{0}, which is not R. I know that P(XY=0)=0, but from what I know in those entry level courses, a normal distribution not only has a pdf that resembles a normal but also has full support over R, not R{0}.

You can find more information about the support of a random variable here.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{\mathrm{supp}}$
There is a bit of confusion about the support of random variables.
The support of a random variable $Z$ is defined as the support of its distribution $\P(Z\in\cdot)$, which is the set of the points whose every open neighbohrood $N$ has the property that $\P(Z\in N)>0$, that is
$$\supp(Z):=\{z:\mathbb P(Z\in N)>0,\forall N\text{ neighbohrood of $z$}\}.$$
Thus, acting as the function $g(x,y)$ from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$, $Z$ doesn't take the value $z=0$; but, acting as the random variable $Z=g(X,Y),$ $Z$ does take the value $z=0$, in the sense that $0\in\supp(Z)$. To see that, we'll compute the distribution of $Z$ and we'll find out that
$$\mathbb P(Z\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon))>0, \: \forall\varepsilon>0.$$
Define $X':=-X$. Conditioning on the sign of $XY$, we get
\begin{align}
F_Z(z)&=\P(Z\le z)\\&=\P(XY>0)\P(Z\le z\mid XY>0) \\&+ \P(XY<0)\P(Z\le z\mid XY<0)\\&=\P(XY>0)\P(X\le z\mid XY>0) \\&+ \P(XY<0)\P(-X\le z\mid XY<0)\\&=\P(XY>0)\P(X\le z\mid XY>0) \\&+ \P(X'Y>0)\P(X'\le z\mid X'Y>0)\\&=2\P(XY>0)\P(X\le z\mid XY>0)\\&=2\P(X\le z, XY>0).
\end{align}
The penultimate equality holds because $(X,XY)$ and $(X',X'Y)$ are identically distributed. Conditioning on the sign of $Y$, we get
\begin{align}
F_Z(z)&=2\P(X\le z, XY>0)\\&=2\P(Y>0)\P(X\le z, XY>0\mid Y>0)\\&+2\P(Y<0)\P(X\le z, XY>0\mid Y<0)\\&=\P(X\le z, XY>0\mid Y>0)\\&+\P(X\le z, XY>0\mid Y<0)\\&=\P(X\le z, X>0\mid Y>0)\\&+\P(X\le z, X<0\mid Y<0)\\&=\P(X\le z, X>0)\\&+\P(X\le z, X<0).
\end{align}
The last equality holds because $X$ and $Y$ are independent. We have
\begin{align}
F_Z(z)&=\P(X\le z, X>0)+\P(X\le z, X<0)\\&=
\begin{cases}
0+\P(X\le z),&\text{if $z\le0$,}\\
\P(0\le X\le z)+\P(X\le 0),&\text{if $z\ge0$,}
\end{cases}\\&=F_X(z).
\end{align}
Thus, $Z$ is $\mathrm{N}(0,1)$-distributed too. Finally note that $0\in\supp(Z)$ because $$\mathbb P(Z\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon))>0, \: \forall\varepsilon>0.$$

Perhaps a simpler proof is like that: $Z=|Z|\cdot sign(Z)$, and $|Z|=|X|$, i.e. the absolute value of the $N(0,1)$ distribution. At the same time for any $a\ge 0$, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$$
\mathbb P(|Z|>a,sign(Z)=+1)=\mathbb P(|X|>a,sign(XY)=+1)=
\mathbb P(|X|>a,sign(X)=1, sign(Y)=+1)+\mathbb P(|X|>a,sign(X)=-1, sign(Y)=-1)=
\mathbb P(|X|>a,sign(X)=1)\mathbb P(sign(Y)=+1)+\mathbb P(|X|>a,sign(X)=-1)\mathbb P(sign(Y)=-1)=
\frac12\left[\mathbb P(|X|>a,sign(X)=1)+\mathbb P(|X|>a,sign(X)=-1)
\right]=\frac12 \mathbb P(|X|>a)=\mathbb P(|Z|>a)\cdot \mathbb P(sign(Z)=+1)
$$
yielding that $|Z|$ and $sign(Z)$ are independent. So $Z=+|X|$ with probability $1/2$ and $Z=-|X|$ with probability $1/2$, which means that $Z$ is $N(0,1)$ from the symmetry of the normal distribution.
